# Phantom manager could not start all workers

Tags: express, pdf, phantomjs, ejs, html-to-pdf

I trying to create a pdf using phamton-html-to-pdf and ejs for templating. The setup work greate in my local dev env, but not in production. The problem is that in my server prod the pdf is created but it is empty.

```js
const ejs = require('ejs');
const fs = require('fs');
const conversion = require("phantom-html-to-pdf")({
  phantomPath: require("phantomjs-prebuilt").path
});



function createPdf  (data, template, directory) {

 var options = {};
 var html = ejs.renderFile(__dirname + `/template/${template}.ejs`,  {data: data}, options, function(err, str){
  if(err){
   return err
  }
     return str
 });

 var filepath = null

 conversion({ html: html, printDelay: 5000}, (err, pdf) => {
    var output = fs.createWriteStream(`documents/${directory}/${data.Référence}.pdf`)
    pdf.stream.pipe(output);
 });
}

module.exports = createPdf;
```

```
{ Error: phantom manager could not start all workers..
at /home/website/group-auto.com/node_modules/phantom-workers/lib/phantomManager.js:66:47
at /home/website/group-auto.com/node_modules/phantom-workers/lib/phantomWorker.js:115:24
at /home/website/group-auto.com/node_modules/phantom-workers/lib/phantomWorker.js:140:20
at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/website/group-auto.com/node_modules/phantom-workers/lib/checkPortStatus.js:45:9)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
at TCP._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:497:12)


[ { Error: Command failed: /home/website/group-auto.com/node_modules/phantom-workers/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=yes --web-security=false --ssl-protocol=any /home/website/group-auto.com/node_modules/phantom-html-to-pdf/lib/scripts/serverScript.js
 /home/website/group-auto.com/node_modules/phantom-workers/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: 1: /home/website/group-auto.com/node_modules/phantom-workers/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: Syntax error: word unexpected (expecting ")")

     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:198:12)
     at emitTwo (events.js:106:13)
     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:191:7)
     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:920:16)
     at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:351:11)
     at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
     at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
     at Pipe._handle.close [as _onclose] (net.js:497:12)
   killed: false,
   code: 2,
   signal: null,
   cmd: '/home/website/group-auto.com/node_modules/phantom-workers/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs --ignore-ssl-errors=yes --web-security=false --ssl-protocol=any /home/website/group-auto.com/node_modules/phantom-html-to-pdf/lib/scripts/serverScript.js' },
```

I have no idea where to look for error, please help

Comment: I'm facing same issue. did you got the solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to install 'libfontconfig' in your server.

- macOS sierra update works only with phantomjs2.
- linux may need to additionally install fontconfig package.
- Centos - sudo yum install -y fontconfig
- Debian/Ubuntu - sudo apt-get install -y libfontconfig

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with phantom-html-to-pdf (0.5.6).
In my case, my config was :

```js
const pdf = require("phantom-html-to-pdf")({
    // number of allocated phantomjs processes
    numberOfWorkers: 3,
    // timeout in ms for html conversion, when the timeout is reached, the phantom process is recycled
    timeout: 10000,
    // directory where are stored temporary html and pdf files
    tmpDir: __dirname + "/tmp/", 
    phantomPath: "/usr/bin/phantomjs"
});
```

But my phantomPath was useless cause they're no executable at **phantomPath** in my case (we propably remove it for some reasons).

```js
const pdf = require("phantom-html-to-pdf")({
    // number of allocated phantomjs processes
    numberOfWorkers: 3,
    // timeout in ms for html conversion, when the timeout is reached, the phantom process is recycled
    timeout: 10000,
    // directory where are stored temporary html and pdf files
    tmpDir: __dirname + "/tmp/"
});
```

My config without phantomPath works !